# Region coloring with customized path selection by live paint bucket tool in adobe illustrator cc

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm gonna choose a set of lines (solid and dashed) in my artwork, then coloring the surrounded region by live paint bucket tool. Here is my artwork:

[image]

All I need is coloring the sphere's section surrounded by two dashed lines, two red lines, and the sphere's boundary, i.e. somewhere like figure below (red region, for example):

[image]

But I have two problems:

1- As I watched some videos on youtube, when one selects live paint bucket tool, all of the possible regions in the artwork must be detected, automatically; but in my case only a subset of regions are detected by the tool, as following:

[image]
[image]
[image]

So, the target regions are not detected by the tool.

2- As I select the desired lines to build a path consisting those lines, live paint bucket tool does still not detect the region middle of the path. Maybe this is not the right way to introduce a new region to the tool.

**Could you please give me some advice in this case?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin by selecting the **entire** shape (including all paths) with the black arrow tool and then start painting with the live paint bucket. I replicated your shape and had no issues filling the portions of the shape as per your diagram.

Comment: Thanks... Actually I did that, but as I said, the tool does not find my target area! Whole the thing it can detect are the 3 areas presented above...

Comment: Hmmm, okay. When you are using your live paint bucket, it looks like you're trying to fill with no fill. With the live paint bucket tool active, what happens if you press the right arrow on your keyboard two or three times and then try again?

Comment: Are the dashed vertical lines on another layer that's locked? What does the image looks like in outline mode (Cmd or Ctrl-Y)?

Comment: Amazingly, nothing! I pretty know that your mentioned approach is the right way, but seemingly I've done something wrong within the drawing process such that bucket tool does not work well...
As I continued on a new file of the image, what you said is working, now! Thanks, anyway

Comment: Good to hear it's working.

Comment: With the live paint bucket tool active, press the enter/return key. Under options, you should have Paint Fills selected in order for the tool to work as you are hoping. I'm wondering if perhaps Paint Strokes is selected instead. EDIT: That setting would persist when you open a new document, and since it worked for you when you did so, I'm guessing you had this set correctly. Anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Ungroup, unlock and expand everything. Make sure they're on the same layer. Select red fill, no stroke. Select everything with the black arrow, open live paint bucket and you should be able to fill the desired regions. When done with red, select blue fill, select the artwork then open live paint bucket again to fill the blue regions.